# C++ Vector elements' index

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, rotation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};

 }
```

Is there an efficient way to push "4" to 1's place and push every other element to the next index. So that the vector's element order is {4, 1, 2, 3} instead. I have thought of a few ways, but i was wondering if there is an elegant and more efficient way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not showed us your solution so we cannot let you know if we know of a more elegant or more efficient solution. Furthermore, if you have a working solution then this question might be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ **but you must supply the code**.

Comment: The answers provide an easy solution, but not efficient. You have the wrong container for what you are asking. Vector is very good at what it is designed for, so I assume you need vector for other reasons, but it will not rotate as quickly as list or deque. (assuming large data size)

Comment: Common answer to that problem is not changing vector at all but change index value you accessing.

Answer (score 6):

This looks tailor-made for std::rotate:

```
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin()+3, v.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use standard algorithm `std::rotate` as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for ( int val : v ) std::cout << val << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::rotate( std::begin( v ), std::prev( std::end( v ) ), std::end( v ) );

    for ( int val : v ) std::cout << val << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However a more efficient approach for such a vector of integer numbers is to use manually standard C function `std::memmove` as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for ( int val : v ) std::cout << val << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int value = v.back();
    std::memmove( v.data() + 1, v.data(), ( v.size() - 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
    v[0] = value;

    for ( int val : v ) std::cout << val << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the both cases the output is

```
1 2 3 4 
4 1 2 3
```

Comment: Recommending memmove over rotate doesn't seem like such a good idea. Maybe complain to your compiler vendor if they don't generate good code for rotate?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I think that instead of to complain to the vendor it is better to write efficient code if you need such.:)